# Good way to balance readability and performance of my code?

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program to do a simple math problem and I can't find a good way to get both code readability and performance :

Given a List of `Node` class and initial value of `rank` ( a double value with some mathematical meaning ) for each Node.
Calculate new `rank` for each node based on old `rank` value using some algorithm. Use the newly calculated `rank` value as old value and repeat the calculation process for multiple times.

```
// this code snippet is pseudo code and does not compile

class Node {
   private int property1;
   ....
   private int propertyN;
   .... //getters and setters
}

List<Node> nodes;
Map<Node,Double> rankold;
Map<Node,Double> ranknew;

void doOneIteration()    {
    foreach (node in nodes) {
         ranknew.put(node,someAlgorithm(rankold));
    }
    rankold = ranknew;
    ranknew = {};
}

void doCalcuation(int times)  {
    nodes = [...];
    rankold = {...};
    ranknew = {};
    while (times-->0) {
       doOneIteration();
    }
}
```

This code snippet are easiest to read. It separates rank logic from the node classes so it's easy to maintain.

The problem is about performance.
Creating HashMap and Double instances uses some extra CPU and Memory resources. and `someAlgorithm()` is simple but the number of Nodes is large.

And I wrote another version without using map:

```
class Node {
   private int property1;
   ....
   private int propertyN;
   private double rank1;
   private double rank2;
   .... //getters and setters
}
List<Node> nodes;
boolean useRank1 = true;

void doOneIteration()    {
    if (useRank1 ) {
         someAlgorithmUseRank1(nodes));
    } else {
         someAlgorithmUseRank2(nodes));
    }
    useRank1 = !useRank1;
}
```

This code snippet minimize memory usage but I will copy code of `someAlgorithm()` twice and if I made any change to `someAlgorithm()` there are two block of code to edit and I think this is "not elegant".

Here's a third code snippet I considered:

```
boolean useRank1 = true;
class Node {
   private double rank1;
   private double rank2;
   double getRank() { if (useRank1) return rank1; else return rank2;}
   void setRank(double r) { if (useRank1) rank2=r; else rank1=r;}       
}
List<Node> nodes;

void doOneIteration()    {
    someAlgorithm(nodes);
    useRank1 = !useRank1;
}
```

The problem is that the `if` branch in the getter and setter will be called multiple times which is not necessary. There is branch prediction and other many runtime optimizations in modern CPU and compilers but I am not sure how good will they work. Another concern is that this code snippet slightly increase the memory use of `Node` class since `Node` will have a pointer to the class holding `useRank1` (although compared to object header one pointer is small)

The question is that is there good way to write "good" code for my problem? (good at CPU & Mem, and easy to read / maintain)

Comment: Can you put the rank into the `Node`?

Comment: Readability does not imply perfomant.

Comment: `The problem is that the if branch in the getter and setter will be called multiple times which is not necessary.`: [Premature optimisation](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) is, in this case, the root of all evil. You are worrying about a most likely immeasurable benefit in the overall scheme of things.

Comment: I'm confused after reading the first code block. `someAlgorithm(rankold)` will return the **same** value for all nodes, which doesn't make any sense. Does the algorithm really need *all* the old ranks? Does the algorithm need to know the current `Node`?

Comment: [**Write Dumb Code**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html).

Comment: I don't think branch prediction is of any help here, not when the branch destination goes back and forth on every iteration.  My understanding is that branch prediction helps when a branch is much more likely to take a branch than not (as in a branch-backwards at the end of a loop), or much more likely to fall through than to branch.